# mobile phone internet browser for pc

Tags: javascript, iphone, android, html, jquery-mobile

I've had a look and I can't seem to find any mobile phone browser emulator which I can use on my pc. I'm writing a javascript / html5 game engine, and it would be nice to test all of the features within a mobile phone browser.

Do you know of any, and where I can download them?

**I've found a great tool just this second!**

http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/mobile/

Can simply install it to the desktop, no need for an emulator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can download the firefox mobile browser for testing.
http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/mobile/

Answer (score 1):

You can use the android emulator, which comes with the stock browser for your testing purposes.

Answer (score 1):

There's a free tool (Chrome Extension) called **[Ripple](http://ripple.tinyhippos.com/)** (which was bought by RIM):

> Test and debug your HTML5 mobile applications for multiple platforms.
> All from within your browser and in a fraction of the time.

Not sure how well it works in emulator device quirks.

Answer (score 0):

The AVD emulators have a fully functional browser. Those do the job nicely for me.

Answer (score 0):

for the one who have a Mac system you've got the full iOS Simultor who allow you to surf the web :
[Here](http://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action)

It's totaly free and really better than Android emulator (stability and speed (I'm just talking about the simulator guys :) )), but a Mac is needed.